# Using different simulation functions in each core with parallel::clusterApply() in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to use the **parallel** package for my study. However, each simulation has different parameters. I tried the code below, but it did not work.

```
require(snow)
library(parallel)

tasks = list(
  job1 = function(t, n) sim(t=5, n=30),
  job2 = function(t, n) sim(t=5, n=50)
)

cl = makeCluster( length(tasks) )
clusterExport(cl, ls())


out = clusterApply(cl, tasks, function(f) f(t, n))
```

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parallel::parLapply()` for this:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)

## simulation function
sim <- function(t, n){
    ## do things
    paste0("input args are: t=", t, ", n=", n)
}
clusterExport(cl, "sim")

## argument configurations
args <- list(config1=list(t=10, n=1),
             config2=list(t=20, n=2))

## run the function for all argument configurations in parallel
parLapply(cl=cl, X=args, fun=function(x) do.call(sim, x))
$config1
[1] "input args are: t=10, n=1"

$config2
[1] "input args are: t=20, n=2"
```